# Loading remote HTML using this.http.get

Tags: angular

I am trying to load some HTML from a remote URL that I control, I want to then display this on my site.

I am using the following code to display my HTML:

```
<div [innerHTML]="headerHTML"></div>
```

To load the content I am using:

```
this.http.get('https://www.server.com/snippet.php')
.subscribe((res) => {
  this.headerHTML = res.text();
});
```

But this converts the HTML in my response into text and removes the HTML tags.

If I try without `.text()` then I get a `Response` object and don't know how to access the `_body` element that contains the HTML.

```
this.http.get('https://www.server.com/snippet.php')
.subscribe((res) => {
  this.headerHTML = res;
});
```

Comment: did you try by using `<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>` even it has properties to comunicate between parent and child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work so I'll post in case it helps others.

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

I then added this to my constructor:

```
private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
```

I then access the HTML response using:

```
this.headerHTML = this.htmlTransform((<any>res)._body);
```

And my htmlTransform function is:

```
htmlTransform(content) {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
}
```

This successfully allows me to see the HTML in my template when I use:

```
<div [innerHTML]="headerHTML"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
this.http.get('https://www.server.com/snippet.php')
.subscribe((res) => {
  let str = JSON.stringify(res);
  let resJson = JSON.parse(str);
  this.headerHTML = resJson._body;
});
```

This way you could access the the response `_body` without problems.

Comment: I tried this earlier but I get the error - Property '_body' does not exist on type 'Response'